# Trim image during Stitching

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, panoramas

I am stitching multiple images into one. In an intermediate step, I get an image like:

[image]

It isn't necessary at all that the image starts from left and has black region in the right. I want to obtain a rectangular image from this one that doesn't contain the black region. That is, something like:

[image]

Can someone please suggest me a way to do that?

Comment: it could be easy to remove columns which have only black pixels. But for rest you can create many different rectangles and it is hard to say which one is better then other rectangles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to crop out the excess black on the right side of the image:

```
Read the image

Convert to grayscale

Threshold

Apply closing and opening morphology to remove small black and white spots.

Get the surrounding contour

Crop the contour

Save the result
```

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read image
img = cv2.imread('road.jpg')

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# threshold
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(gray,5,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# apply close and open morphology to fill tiny black and white holes
kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)

# get contours (presumably just one around the nonzero pixels) 
# then crop it to bounding rectangle
contours = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    crop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]
    # show cropped image
    cv2.imshow("CROP", crop)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# save cropped image
cv2.imwrite('road_crop.png',crop)
```

[image]

Comment: I expect you want to trim of the top right and bottom right areas of black as well. I have not worked that out, yet. I hope someone with more OpenCV and Numpy experience can add to my answer. One way might be to find the last non-zero pixel in each row and then find the range of longest rows. The image would have to be trimmed a bit more on the right since there are some black pixels even at center right region.